# Python 2.7 - Quotes added to command when using Popen to execute from variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to send a command through a socket from client to server to execute a command on the server and send the output back to me. Everything works fine if the command is one word with no options. However if I use an option such as `netstat -an or dir c:\` then the command isn't recognized and from the output it looks like quotes are put around the command before being executed (`'"netstat -an"'` is not recognized as an internal or external command). I know they aren't saved in the variable this way because I printed it before being executed to error check. Please help. Here is what my code looks like:

```
commout = subprocess.Popen([data], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

(out, err) = commout.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try make `data` an array of arguments (the first being the actual command).

For example:

```
commout = subprocess.Popen(['netstat', '-an'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

The first element is a string representing the actual command (`netstat`), the next element is a string representing the first argument (`-an`).

To clarify, `Popen(['echo', 'a', 'b']` is equivalent to `echo a b` on the command line, whereas `Popen(['echo', 'a b']` would be equivalent to `echo "a b"` instead (ie. a single argument with a space between `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a list, each item in it will be quoted separately. In this case, just pass a string:

```
subprocess.Popen(data, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: Wow...that was so simple after all the frustration. Taking the brackets of [data] worked. I thought I needed the brackets in the case I did have a list. Thank you very much.