# Weird behavior using python3 subprocess.Popen and an argument between quotes

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a project where I take a path as argument and using Tivoli Storage Manager (TSM), I execute a segmented backup of that path tree. 
So far so good.

I discovered a weird behavior when I try to backup of a path with spaces. 
When I use TSM, I put the path in quotes and that works fine. 
On python (3.5.2), on the other hand, when I try to execute the command using subprocess.Popen, the tsm tells me than path could not be found. The weird behavior is that it concatenates the argument path with the current dir.

Once more: it only hapens when it is processing paths with spaces, i.e.  "/appdata/mtmradar/ixd/Autos e Ar/07_821_261_6/"

I already read some questions like [16114713](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114713/python-2-7-quotes-added-to-command-when-using-popen-to-execute-from-variable).

By the way, I found out that when use list of  removing the quotes I can execute the command correctly. **My question is: why it is concatenating my current path with the argument path?**

I am using Python 3.5.2 on AIX 7.2.
The complete command is this:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen
>>> with Popen(['/usr/bin/dsmc', 'i', '-quiet', '-optfile=/usr/tivoli/tsm/client/ba/bin64/dsm-NAS-SDER00019.opt', '-sub=yes', '"/appdata/mtmradar/ixd/Autos e Ar/07_821_261_6/"']) as proc:
...     pass
...
```

This what I got:

```
IBM Tivoli Storage Manager
Command Line Backup-Archive Client Interface
  Client Version 7, Release 1, Level 3.0 
  Client date/time: 07/18/17   10:37:54
(c) Copyright by IBM Corporation and other(s) 1990, 2015. All Rights Reserved.

Node Name: NAS-SDER00019
Session established with server CELBKP03: AIX
  Server Version 7, Release 1, Level 4.100
  Server date/time: 07/18/17   10:38:04  Last access: 07/18/17   10:27:03


Incremental backup of volume '"/appdata/mtmradar/ixd/Autos e Ar/07_821_261_6/"'
ANS1076E The specified directory path '/usr/tivoli/tsm/client/ba/bin64/tsm_seg_bkp_python/NAS-SDER00019/"/appdata/mtmradar/ixd/Autos\ e\ Ar/07_821_261_6/"' could not be found.
```

Executing the same command without the double quotes on the path, I have no errors:

```
>>> with Popen(['/usr/bin/dsmc', 'i', '-quiet', '-optfile=/usr/tivoli/tsm/client/ba/bin64/dsm-NAS-SDER00019.opt', '-sub=no', '/appdata/mtmradar/ixd/Autos e Ar/07_821_261_6/']) as proc:
...     pass 
...
```

This is the output:

```
IBM Tivoli Storage Manager
Command Line Backup-Archive Client Interface
[...]
Incremental backup of volume '/appdata/mtmradar/ixd/Autos e Ar/07_821_261_6/'
Successful incremental backup of '/appdata/mtmradar/ixd/Autos e Ar/07_821_261_6/*'
Total number of objects inspected:            4
[...]
Total data reduction ratio:              100.00%
Elapsed processing time:               00:00:01
```

Comment: Do not use quotes when defining individual arguments for `subprocess.Popen` - it will escape your arguments automatically and tailored to the shell its running them on.

Comment: Thanks,  @zwer . I understand that. my only dout is about  the current path on the path string. I was expecting something different, like just not understand the spaces. I even try to escape the spaces, like '\ ', but it didn't work as well. Latter I discovered the problem is the double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the heavenly world of quoted string processing! ;-)

AIX is a Unix, so when you quote a parameter to a command, the quotes are interpreted by the shell, and the shell actually pass the parameter *with quotes removed* to the command through (a library function calling) execve. If you want to mimic it from Python, you shall not quote any parameter when you pass them as an iterable. If you do, the command will receives a quoted string which is not what is expected.

The error is caused by the parameter starting with a double quote `"` instead of a slash `/`. Only a path starting with a slash is an absolute one, any other initial character (include `"`) causes it to be interpreted as a relative path, hence the concatenation.

So the answer to your question is: *since the parameter does not start with a `/` but with a `"`, it is a relative path that is concatenated to the current path*

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to understand. Thanks a lot!